# Software to Verify Formatting across ebook Readers

Tags: ebook-readers, creation, software, validation

**Is there anything out there to check that your fancy formatting will get displayed properly in ePub, Kindle, Kobo, phone readers, etc?**

Many years ago, when my company first started making eBooks we used to test how they would translate into different readers with a piece of software. We could display the ePub in several generations of Kindle readers and even some phone screen sizes.

Now I'm wondering if it was the old Mobi converter software since that is what we mostly used it to test. Is there any current software that fills that niche?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of Kindle Previewer, although it looks like they have removed all the various kindle versions and now just give you the three options of phone, tablet, or eReader.

Going to leave the question open to see if there is a piece of software that spans a few readers.

Comment: Online validators, e.g., https://www.ebookit.com/tools/bp/Bo/eBookIt/epub-validator